# std::filesystem says that i have all permissions for system files

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems, file-permissions, ntfs

I'm trying to get permissions for a file using `std::filesystem` API

```
auto stdPerms = std::filesystem::status(path).permissions();
```

when i pass any file (like C:\MyTestFile or C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) it always returns me the same value of `std::filesystem::perms::all` however it is known that i can't edit `hosts` file without Administrator rights. What am i doing wrong? What workarounds or libraries (maybe) can handle that kind of issue for me. I can also use raw WinAPI calls but i don't want a much of overhead and there's only a `std::string path` in my disposal

Example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <filesystem>
int main()
{
    auto path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts";
    auto stdPerms = std::filesystem::status(path).permissions();
    assert(stdPerms != std::filesystem::perms::all);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
Assertion failed: stdPerms != std::filesystem::perms::all, file C:\Dev****.cpp, line 8

Comment: how are you running your code?

Comment: @berto99 what do you mean under "how"? I run it in GTest

Comment: I can't reproduce with ".../etc/hosts". Please post a [mcve].